# Share links hitting auth error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access sharing links via the Graph API. Following the below page to access the images `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get`

I am hitting an auth error on this URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9vbmVkcml2ZS5saXZlLmNvbS9yZWRpcj9yZXNpZD0xNUI2OEIxRjRCMUMyNTAzITMyOCZhdXRoa2V5PSFBSUNfRGZ1YnpGa20zazAmdj0zJml0aGludD1waG90byUyY3BuZw/root?$expand=children`

The same link but using the OneDrive API works: `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9vbmVkcml2ZS5saXZlLmNvbS9yZWRpcj9yZXNpZD0xNUI2OEIxRjRCMUMyNTAzITMyOCZhdXRoa2V5PSFBSUNfRGZ1YnpGa20zazAmdj0zJml0aGludD1waG90byUyY3BuZw/root?$expand=children`

Have I missed any steps on converting the URL? From what I can tell the documentation is the same across both Graph and OneDrive APIs.

Comment: Could you provide the scopes you are requesting and actual error content you're getting? This will narrow down where the problem is.